# How i can change my assign user role in wordpress 3.5.1 database

Tags: wordpress

This time my user role is 'Admin' but i have to change my role 'Editor' by change in database and give to assign that role.

I also read it

Here's [a link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)!

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use `WordPress Admin Console > Users > Edit` ?

Comment: i know ,But i have to required where to store actual in database.

Answer (score 1):

There is a table called wp_usemeta. In it, there is a setting for your admin user's priviledges. You'll find a field that contains something like "a:1:{s:6:"administrator";b:1;}", and you want to change it to be "a:1:{s:13:"editor";b:1;}". (not including the quotes).

Back up the mysql database first beforehand in case it's further broken.

[Credits](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-user-roles)

Comment: can you explain the parameters of JSON string ?

Comment: @sunil silumala..In your answer we can change the value of 's:13' insted of 's:6' when as a 'administrator'.otherwise given a error.

Comment: Final answer got it. wp_usermeta ->a:1:{s:6:"editor";s:1:"1";} insted of  a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";} field. 'S' for number of character in string